# High values of cpu load

Tags: command-line, uptime

The system `uptime` command is returning values above `5`... This is a high value right? What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: run `sudo top` command and see what process is taking up your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try with command

```
top
```

to see process witch make load. Also you can use command

```
ps -aef --forest
```

to see child process of main process